# Docker not finding php's mysql extension

Tags: php, docker

I'm using docker-compose to create a wordpress environment and for PHP, my docker file is just:

```
# https://github.com/alterway/docker-php
FROM alterway/php:5.5-fpm

WORKDIR "/var/www/httpdocs/web”
```

But for some reason, php complaints it cannot find the mysql_* functions, which is weird, because `alterway/php:5.5-fpm` ( https://github.com/alterway/docker-php/blob/master/5.5-fpm/Dockerfile#L30 ) contains the install instruction for the mysql extension.

If i make my Dockerfile:

```
# https://github.com/alterway/docker-php
FROM alterway/php:5.5-fpm

# add this
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysql

WORKDIR "/var/www/httpdocs/web”
```

Then it works, but why should i do it if the instruction already exists in the `alterway/php:5.5-fpm` Dockerfile ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out you have to load the extensions manually as shown in the docs at : https://github.com/alterway/docker-php/blob/master/doc-php-fpm.md#load-php-extensions (but who reads them :-s )

Once the extensions were listed, it worked great.